# IOS (Safari/Chrome): div with flex-direction:column-reverse has wrong scroll behavior (bug?)

Tags: javascript, css, ios, flexbox, scroll

I got a simple div with `flex-direction:column-reverse` and a button, which adds content to the given div.

In Chrome, Firefox, Edge on Windows and in Chrome and Firefox on my Galaxy S21 Ultra I have following expected behavior:

When I add values to the div, the div still stays at the scroll position 0 (which is the bottom, since it is column-reverse). So new elements are added till the div is to big for the div and then more values are added outside the view (so I have to scroll to see them).

In IOS (Safari or Chrome of e.g. an iPhone 13), the behavior is different: When I add new values, the div scrolls on every added value instead of staying on scroll position 0. And after adding multiple values, the values are invisible. They magically appear again after manually scrolling by hand.

If I change the div from

`flex-direction:column-reverse` to `flex-direction:coloumn`, the behavior is as expected: it stays on scroll position 0.

Here a simple example. Open it on an IOS mobile device to see the "wrong" behavior.

```js
var values = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7"];
var counter = 8;

var addFunction = () => {
    values = [...values, "value"+counter];
    counter++;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = renderContent();
}

var renderContent = () => {
    return values.map(v => "<p>"+v+"</p>").join("\n");
}
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = renderContent();
```

```css
.outerdiv {
  position: relative; 
  height: 90vh;
}

.content {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column-reverse; 
  background-color: #ffa; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 2.3rem; 
  left: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  overflow: auto;
}

.addButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div id="content" class="content">

  </div>
  <button class="addButton" onClick={addFunction()}>+ Add</button>
</div>
```

How can you fix this? I want the scroll position staying at 0;

Even if I add the following scroll logic to the addFunction(), it only works in IOS after I scrolled once by hand:

```
document.getElementById("content").scrollTo({top: 0,left: 0,behavior: "smooth"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the same problem:

Only workaround I found is to scroll to position -1, instead of scrolling to 0.

What does **not** work:

```
var addFunction = () => {
   //...
   document.getElementById("content").scrollTo({
       top: 0, //<-- not working in IOS after first render
       left: 0,
       behavior: "smooth"
   }); 
}
```

What does work:

```
var addFunction = () => {
   //...
   document.getElementById("content").scrollTo({
       top: 0, //<-- scroll to -1 instead of 0
       left: 0,
       behavior: "smooth"
   }); 
}
```

IOS has the weird behavior, that scrolling to 0 is not working at the beginning (after first render). But it does work, after you scrolled once manually by hand. If I scroll to -1 instead of 0, it also works after the first render (so you don't need to touch the scroll-div before).

I would be very grateful if someone could give me a cleaner solution.